# Can you prevent call of constructor without instantiation?

Tags: c++

Simplified snip of my class:

```
class UpdatingSystem
/* when system is "unsafe" it marks this condition by instantiating an
UpdatingSystem item. While this item exists errors are handled in a 
particular way. When the UpdatingSystem item goes out of scope error
handling reverts to normal.*/
{
private:
static THREAD int updatingSystemCount_;

public:
UpdatingSystem(const char* caller){updatingSystemCount++};
~UpdatingSystem(){updatingSystemCount--};
};
```

This works:

```
{
    UpdatingSystem tempUnsafe("Reason it's unsafe");
    // do stuff that requires the system be 'unsafe' 
} // Revert to safe when destructor runs
```

This doesn't:

```
{
    UpdatingSystem("Reason it's unsafe");
    // do stuff that requires the system be 'unsafe' 
}
```

... because the called constructor creates a temporary item and the destructor immediately runs, leaving the system as "safe" when it shouldn't be.

It's easy to make the mistake of writing the second, faulty, version.
Is there a way to prevent such a call of the constructor without instantiation?

Comment: There is no way to prevent that, no. C++ allows anonymous temporaries, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: No, the class has no way of knowing that the object is saved in an lvalue.

Comment: I know I deleted it,, Miss read the question :) its early still having coffee :)

Comment: The only way to extend the lifetime of a temporary is to bind it to a references (lvalue const/rvalue). But it's no better than introducing a temporary.

Comment: You could wrap the temporary in a macro (along with using the preprocessor for creating the temporary names), and `(void)` as well to avoid a warning. But it's all just syntactic sugar.

Comment: If you want to be strict, then make your object an execution controlling object where you pass in the logic to be protected. That way you CANNOT make that mistake. Kind of like a thread pool type mechanism, where you can decorate/protect the logic the way you want.

Comment: Rob's advice is spot on. Here's a longer explanation of how to achieve something similar for on-the-fly RAII, by [Alexandrescu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjTrfoiB0MQ) .

Comment: Could you explain that a little more please, or give an example?

Comment: I seem to recall seeing another answer posted here a few days ago (involving warn_unused_result attribute, I think) but I no longer see it. Has it been removed or was that just a festive figment of my imagination? A ghost of Christmas solutions yet to be, perhaps!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to prevent such a call of the constructor without
>   instantiation?

No, you can't control how users instantiate your class.

Perhaps a better *name* would encourage proper use, something like:

```
class SystemUpdateGuard {..}

{
    SystemUpdateGuard guard_system_update("Reason it's unsafe");
    // do stuff that requires the system be 'unsafe' 
} // Revert to safe when destructor runs
```

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly want to prohibit temporaries you could do some trickery.

Make `UpdatingSystem`'s constructor `private`, create a factory class that only accepts a reference to a `unique_ptr<UpdatingSystem>`. This way it requires an lvalue and because of the smart pointer the object will be destroyed once out of scope, something [like](http://ideone.com/DGvTBT):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class UpdatingSystem
{
    friend class UpdatingSystemFactory;
    public:
    ~UpdatingSystem() { std::cout << "destructor UpdatingSystem"; }
    private:
    UpdatingSystem() { std::cout << "constructor UpdatingSystem";}
};

class UpdatingSystemFactory
{
    public:
    static void GenerateUpdatingSystem(std::unique_ptr<UpdatingSystem>& ptr)
    {
        ptr = std::unique_ptr<UpdatingSystem>(new UpdatingSystem());
    }
};

int main() 
{
    //..when having to create an updating system:
    {
      std::unique_ptr<UpdatingSystem> tmp;
      UpdatingSystemFactory::GenerateUpdatingSystem(tmp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you could just use a static function in the `UpdatingSystem` class that generates a `unique_ptr`. Like this: `static unique_ptr<UpdatingSystem> UpdatingSystem::Create()`. Saves you creating a whole new class just to create the pointer :-)

Comment: Thanks Gill, that looks to be what I need.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion too Karl

Answer (score 1):

What about a guard like this:

```
...
UpdatingSystem(const char* caller, std::function<void()> func)
{
    updatingSystemCount++;
    f();
    updatingSystemCount--;
};
...

UpdatingSystem("whatever", [&](){ do_unsafe_stuff(); });
```

Comment: I like this approach. This basically achieves what OP wants by wrapping the unsafe code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an architectural problem.

Sadly the only solution is to modify your unsafe functions.  They must require the UpdatingSystem object.

In the end your code should look like this...

```
{
    UpdatingSystem tempUnsafe("Reason it's unsafe");
    unsafe_operation(tempUnsafe);
    safe_operation();
    another_unsafe_operation(tempUnsafe, 42);
} // Revert to safe when destructor runs
```

This solves your problem by making it impossible to perform unsafe operations without first creating an `UpdatingSystem` object.

Updating the unsafe functions is easy, just pass it a reference.  You don't even need to do anything with the object or copy it.

```
another_unsafe_operation(UpdatingSystem const & lock, int data)
{
    // Do stuff, you don't even need to use the lock for anything.
}
```

This approach generally makes life easier for programmers as well because it's the only way to force them to handle unsafe functions correctly.

If it is 'impossible' to define safety at the function level in this way then you may need to rethink your program's abstractions.